# How can I sum the values of cells in a row more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

Hello I've searched and tried for a long time but I just can't get it. 
On the picture you can see my Google Sheet.

**I just want to add up all the numbers in the row that are <= 10.**

How can I simplify the code from below? Does anyone have an idea?
Many thanks!

---

[image: Picture of the project]

---

```js
function calculationFirstColumn() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var originalData = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() -1, 1).getValues();

var filteredItems = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==1}).length;
var filteredItems2 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==2}).length;
var filteredItems3 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==3}).length;
var filteredItems4 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==4}).length;
var filteredItems5 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==5}).length;
var filteredItems6 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==6}).length;
var filteredItems7 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==7}).length;
var filteredItems8 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==8}).length;
var filteredItems9 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==9}).length;
var filteredItems10 = originalData.filter(function(x){return x==10}).length;

var total = filteredItems+filteredItems2+filteredItems3+filteredItems4+filteredItems5+
            filteredItems6+filteredItems7+filteredItems8+filteredItems9+filteredItems10;

sheet.getRange("B18").setValue(total); 


}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a `for` loop?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Could you maybe help me with the "for loop" code?

Comment: Sorry, no. You'll need to show your effort and ask a more specific question. As it is you're mostly looking for code review. I'd revise to start fresh with a loop. Then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use filters, instead use a combination of a loop and conditional statement:

```
function calculationFirstColumn() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var originalData = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() -1, 1).getValues();
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < originalData.length; i++){
    if(originalData[i][0] <= 10){
      total += originalData[i][0];
    }
    Logger.log(total);
  }
  sheet.getRange("B18").setValue(total); 
}
```

Comment: The numbers are added up. I would like to use the function to count how often a number occurs in the column.
Example:
if (originalData [i] [0] == 13) {
The function writes a 13 on the sheet with this line.
But what I want him to do is write a 1 because the number 13 is only once in the first column.

Comment: In this case: `if (originalData [i] [0] == 13) { total++;}` will increment total by 1 each time an 13 is found.

Comment: and if I want to count all the numbers that are under 10? unfortunately this does not work if (originalData [i] [0] <= 10) { total++;}

Comment: It does, but you have to make sure not to count empty cells: `if(originalData[i][0] <= 10 && originalData[i][0] !=''){
      total ++;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

is a script really necessary for something like this?

=SUMIF(B2:B,"<=10",B2:B)

Answer (score 0):

@ziganotschka **ThankYOU!** 
Your last answer works. But I still have an *understanding* question.

### [NO EMPTY CELL - PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed3wr.png)

**original data**. The area to be evaluated is clearly defined and there is no empty cell in it. Then why does this function need the instruction?

```
if(originalData[i][0] <= 10 /*&& originalData[i][0] !=''*/){ total ++; }
```

Which cells does this function count without this additional line?